# How to have QuickFIX connection which last for more than a week

Tags: quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj, quickfixn

Is there any way through coding or configuration to create FIX session which lasts for more than a week.

I checked the [Configuring QuickFIX](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html), but i cannot find any information there.

Comment: two down votes to question after few months its posted. please comment and down-vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think any version of QuickFIX allows this.

However, I'm unaware of any FIX party that uses a longer-than-weeklong session.  (I'm not even sure if the FIX specification permits that.)

Answer (score 2):

You can have session as long as you want. In QuickFixJ there is a configuration
NonStopSession=Y
(https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/1.6.4/usage/configuration.html).

In your application, who is terminating the connection? Is it Acceptor or Initiator?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure start day as monday and end day as sunday to run the session for entire week.

Please look for startDay and EndDay at https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/1.6.4/usage/configuration.html